# Necesito Ayuda con async Task .

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-asynctask, asynctask

[image: Este error me sale]

Cuand ocreo un método me aparece en rojo y me sale ese error de la imagen.
por favor alguien me ayuda?

Comment: Es recomendable que pegues el código en lugar de una imagen. También para futuras búsquedas pon el error como texto en este post.

Comment: En efecto, la clase `Response` debe ser declarada como `public`.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que intenta decirte el error de compilación es que la clase `Response` es menos accesible que el método `CheckConnection`.

Como tu método es `public` la clase `Response` también tiene que ser `public`. Probablemente esté como `internal`.

Puedes leer más sobre esto aquí: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/restrictions-on-using-accessibility-levels

Comment: jajajajajaja... pucha verdad.. no era pública la clase Response jaja.. Que despistado, MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: @JoelRm fijate de editar la pregunta así le sirve a otros.